# JS Работа с высотой

Tags: javascript, html, height

Ребят помогите, нужен js скрипт который будет делать следующее:
Высота дивов с классами .rightside .leftside зависит от класса .container и прибовляет высоте значение +20px, тобишь что должно в итоге получится:

JS Берет высоту контейнера и задает ее двум дивам и прибавляет еще сверху +20px

P.S Надеюсь это будет не сложно, заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в Ваш вопрос код, который Вы написали и попробовали выполнить. Опишите, что получилось, и как это отличается от ожидаемого.

Comment: С таким вопросом вам [туда](http://pogugli.com/?80211) либо [туда](http://fl.ru/). Ведь это действительно совсем не сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.leftside,.rightside').height($('.container').height() + 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Высоту дива можно померять с помощью jQuery:

```
$('.rightside').height();
```

Кладём всё в меременные, складываем и прибавляем нужное значение и получится что вам нужно.
Задать высоту можно через:

```
$('.leftside').css('height', '200px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$perem = parseInt($('.container').height());
$('.rightside').css('height', perem+20);
$('.leftside').css('height', perem+20);
```